# Arguments mismatch for instruction 'ld' and 'add'

Tags: cuda

I would like to know why the following `asm` instructions inside a cuda code

```
__global__ void access( double *posArray )
{
  uint32_t tid = threadIdx.x;
  double sink = 0;
  for(uint32_t i = tid; i < L1_SIZE; i += THREADS_NUM) {
    double* ptr = posArray+i;
    asm volatile("{\t\n"
                 ".reg .f32 data;\n\t"
                 "ld.global.ca.f64 data, [%1];\n\t"
                 "add.f64 %0, data, %0;\n\t"
                 "}" : "+d"(sink) : "l"(ptr) : "memory"
    );
  }
  // synchronize all threads
  asm volatile("bar.sync 0;");

  for(uint32_t i = 0; i < L1_SIZE; i += THREADS_NUM) {
    double* ptr = posArray+i;
    // every warp loads all data in l1 cache
    for(uint32_t j = 0; j < THREADS_NUM; j += WARP_SIZE) {
      uint32_t offset = (tid+j)%THREADS_NUM/;
      asm volatile("{\t\n"
                   ".reg .f64 data;\n\t"
                   "ld.global.ca.f64 data, [%1];\n\t"
                   "add.f64 %0, data, %0;\n\t"
                   "}" : "+d"(sink) : "l"(ptr+offset) : "memory"
      );
    }
  }
}
```

fail to compile with this output:

```
ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_00003451_00000000-5_l1.ptx, line 63; error   : Arguments mismatch for instruction 'ld'
ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_00003451_00000000-5_l1.ptx, line 64; error   : Arguments mismatch for instruction 'add'
...
...
```

And those two lines repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
             ".reg .f32 data;\n\t"
```

should be changed to:

```
             ".reg .f64 data;\n\t"
```

(which makes it match your second usage/invocation of the inline assembly.)

The error is arising because `data` is an argument to the next 2 instructions:

```
             "ld.global.ca.f64 data, [%1];\n\t"
             "add.f64 %0, data, %0;\n\t"
```

and those instructions both operate on 64-bit floating point operands (`.f64`), not 32-bit floating point operands (`.f32`).